# Who is the second male that was not afraid to take the land in Numbers 14?

Tags: numbers

In the KJV, NKJV, and NLT it only mentions Caleb in Numbers 13:30, though many people, writings, and videos say there were two men. Is there other text, maybe Hebrew that states there was another spy that was not afraid of the inhabitants?

Comment: “Of the tribe of Simeon, Shaphat the son of Hori. Of the tribe of Judah, Caleb the son of Jephunneh. Of the tribe of Issachar, Igal the son of Joseph. Of the tribe of Ephraim, Oshea the son of Nun. Of the tribe of Benjamin, Palti the son of Raphu. Of the tribe of Zebulun, Gaddiel the son of Sodi. Of the tribe of Joseph, namely, of the tribe of Manasseh, Gaddi the son of Susi. Of the tribe of Dan, Ammiel the son of Gemalli. Of the tribe of Asher, Sethur the son of Michael. Of the tribe of Naphtali, Nahbi the son of Vophsi. Of the tribe of Gad, Geuel the son of Machi.

Comment: These are the names of the men which Moses sent to spy out the land. And Moses called Oshea the son of Nun Jehoshua.”
‭‭Numbers‬ ‭13‬:‭5‬-‭16‬ ‭KJV‬‬

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other spy was Joshua:

Numbers 32:10–12 NIV11-GKE

> <sup>**10**</sup> The LORD’S anger was aroused that day and he swore this oath: <sup>**11**</sup> ‘Because they have not followed me wholeheartedly, not one of those who were twenty years old or more when they came up out of Egypt will see the land I promised on oath to Abraham, Isaac and Jacob— <sup>**12**</sup> not one except Caleb son of Jephunneh the Kenizzite and Joshua son of Nun, for they followed the LORD wholeheartedly.’